# Force Docker to cache directory

Tags: caching, go, docker, dockerfile

Is it possible to force Docker to cache a directory?

I would like to do this because I am using vendoring in Go 1.6 (via [Glide](https://glide.sh)) and a majority of my build times are spent fetching the same dependencies as the previous build.

If there is a way of forcing Docker to cache a directory, is there any way to let Docker know when to invalidate the cache (ex., when `glide.lock` changes)?

Comment: why don t you `cp -R ../somewhere/cachedvendors/ project/vendors` all the simply ?

Comment: any luck? I'd like to know this too

Comment: @Catalyst No luck. I used `mh-cbon`'s suggestion of caching on my host machine for a bit and then moved the logic over to a [golang-glide](https://github.com/Noah-Huppert/golang-glide/blob/master/Dockerfile) repository which I havn't needed to use for a while (So I don't remember if this specific problem still occurs)

Comment: @NoahHuppert the next best thing (I've since learned about) is to `RUN <code that generates or copies things based on glide.lock>` right after a line doing `ADD glide.lock`. This way the RUN command is cached unless either it changes, or the line above it is invalidated - in this case when `ADD` detects a change in `glide.lock`